# Where to put the function needing modification in a decorator

Tags: python, decorator

Can someone explain where I'm supposed to put the function so that I can modify it to change all the u's in a given string to t? So far, this only returns none when I modify my function

```
def my_decorator(func):

      def wrapper(**kwargs):  

         for arg in kwargs.values():
            if arg=='u':
               arg.replace('t','u')
         func(**kwargs)

      return wrapper



def reverse_dna(**kwargs):
   results=[]
   for arg in kwargs.values():
      if 'u' in arg:
         return 'this only works for dna'
      else:
         reverse=arg[::-1]
         results.append(reverse)
   return results

@my_decorator
def reverse_dna2(**kwargs):
   results=[]
   for arg in kwargs.values():
      if 'u' in arg:
         return 'this only works for dna'
      else:
         reverse=arg[::-1]
         results.append(reverse)
   return results

print(reverse_dna(a='augc', b='uagcagcagc'))
print(reverse_dna2(a='augc', b='uagcagcagc'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things you didn't do;

- You need to replace the value in `kwargs` itself
- You didn't return the value after calling the function, you just called it and forgot to use `return`.

*

```
$ cat reverse_dna.py
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(**kwargs):  
        for key, val in kwargs.items():
            kwargs[key] = val.replace('u', 't')
        return func(**kwargs)
    return wrapper

@my_decorator
def reverse_dna2(**kwargs):
   results=[]
   for arg in kwargs.values():
      if 'u' in arg:
         return 'this only works for dna'
      else:
         reverse=arg[::-1]
         results.append(reverse)
   return results

print(reverse_dna2(a='augc', b='uagcagcagc'))
```

**Output:**

```
$ python reverse_dna.py
['cgta', 'cgacgacgat']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have several flaws.

- First, I am not clear whether `a` and `b` have some importance here; it seems to me that you'd better off without them: do `def reverse_dna(*args):` and just iterate over `args`.
- Second, I stumble over

  > ```
  > if arg=='u':
  >     arg.replace('t','u')
  > ```

  The way it is written, the code does nothing: first, `arg` is never `'u'`, and if it was, there was no `t` which could be replaced with a `u` (wrong order!), and if there was, you'd never make use of the replacement result.

I'd do something like

```
def my_decorator(func):
      def wrapper(*args):  
         # In order to replace u with t, do
         #replaced_args = [arg.replace('u', 't') if 'u' in arg else arg for arg in args]
         # or much simpler, as replacing what isn't here is a NOP:
         replaced_args = [arg.replace('u', 't') for arg in args]
         return func(*replaced_args) # return the value! Otherwise your wrapper returns None.
      return wrapper

def reverse_dna(*args):
   results=[]
   for arg in args:
      if 'u' in arg:
         return 'this only works for dna'
      else:
         reverse = arg[::-1]
         results.append(reverse)
   return results

@my_decorator
def reverse_dna2(**kwargs):
   results=[]
   for arg in args:
      if 'u' in arg:
         return 'this only works for dna'
      else:
         reverse = arg[::-1]
         results.append(reverse)
   return results

#print(reverse_dna('augc', 'uagcagcagc'))
print(reverse_dna2('augc', 'uagcagcagc'))
```

I didn't test it, but that should be about the way to go.